# Map result of a sql query to pojo using spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I am a student learning Spring data jpa. I am trying to solve some of practice coding questions. I have a question which i could not find answer to.
I have a database table by name MYDB which has fields:

```
(id, firstname, lastname, rollno, major, country)
```

And i have an sql query like this:

```
select Count(*) as counts, lastname as last_name, major as major_field from MYDB group by country
```

The above query returns three fields: counts(which is not a db column), last_name and major_field.

I have a POJO like this:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private int counts;
    private String lastName;
    private String majorField;

    // Getters and Setters of all data members here
    ...................
}
```

My question is how do i map the result that i got from sql query to my POJO? I need to assign:

```
counts = counts(from sql query), lastName = last_name(from sql query), majorField = major_field(from sql query).
```

I am stuck at this point and do not know how to implement further to map result of sql query to POJO:

```
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyPojo, String> {
    @Query(value=MY_SQL_QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
    List<MyPojo> findAll();
}
```

Ultimately i need to convert MyPojo to a Json object, but i know how to do that part. I am only stuck without ideas about assigning result of sql query to pojo.

Comment: This solved the problem: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions#solution_interface_jpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved using interface-based projections:

```
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions#solution_interface_jpa
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the javax.persistence `@Column` annotation to specify which values from the query are used to populate the fields of the Java object:

```
public class MyPojo {

    @Column(name = "counts")
    private int counts;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    ... and so on
}
```

Here is a great tutorial on the annotations:

- https://www.javaworld.com/article/3373652/java-persistence-with-jpa-and-hibernate-part-1-entities-and-relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use TypedQuery and give your class name for executing and mapping your query result into pojos